# GitPod AWS SSO No access

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-cli, gitpod

I am following the instructions to get AWS SSO working: https://www.gitpod.io/guides/integrate-aws-cli-ecr

I'm not sure about what the `AWS_ROLE_NAME` gitpod variable should be. I feel like I'm getting this wrong, because signing in with:

`aws sso login --no-browser`

and then `aws sts get-caller-identity`

I get `An error occurred (ForbiddenException) when calling the GetRoleCredentials operation: No access`

I've set it to an IAM role name which should have admin access.

Answer (score 1):

resolved - `AWS_ROLE_NAME` needed to be set to AWSPowerUserAccess  or other permission set name, which you can find in https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/#/organization/permission-sets

also, don't forget to go to https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home#/organization/accounts click on an account and assign the SSO user to the account with an appropriate permission set.